# SQL Server : complicated inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, which I want to fill with data. Those tables are `Threads` and `Posts`. Also I have a table called `Source` which contains data.

`Threads` and `Posts` contain a lot of columns to be filled, so I will not paste them here for the sake of simplicity, but most of them can be some fixed value. `Source` table contains following columns - `title` (goes into `Threads.title`), `postContent` (goes into `Posts.content`)

In order to copy data:

1. I need to copy `title` column from `Source` table into `Threads` table, and add some fixed date, and author username into it (I want author to be some constant string, and date to be autogenerated `DateTime` from some T-SQL function)
2. Now when the `Threads` row is created, I need to get it's ID, and create new `Posts` row, which will contain `ID` of new thread, content from `Source.postContent`, and some other fixed values

I know that this probably is complicated, but can you maybe give me some guidelines here? How do I do such a thing? The main issue here, is the need of creating `Threads` first, and then using it's ID in `Posts`.

Comment: You could use cursors.

Comment: *I know that this probably is complicated* Only if you don't know what the `OUTPUT` clause is, yes.

Comment: Are you looking for a function you can call every time you want to insert a new row into `Threads` and `Posts`, or is this a one-time thing?

Comment: @MaxVernon: I mean, I want to do it once and then forget about it, but there is plenty of rows to be inserted (at least few thousands).

Comment: You can create a temp table with ID of the source data and thread ID columns. As you insert threads, update this table. Then you can update the posts from source and look up thread id.

Comment: You can achieve this thing using Merge and TempTable/Table variable. Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Create Table and add dummy data**

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Threads]    Script Date: 11/06/2013 13:57:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Threads](
    [ThreadID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ThreadTitle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Threads] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ThreadID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SourceTable]    Script Date: 11/06/2013 13:57:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable](
    [SourceTableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SourceTitle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SourceContent] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SourceTableID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Posts]    Script Date: 11/06/2013 13:57:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts](
    [PostID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostContent] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ThreadID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Posts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PostID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Posts_Threads]    Script Date: 11/06/2013 13:57:51 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_Threads] FOREIGN KEY([ThreadID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Threads] ([ThreadID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_Threads]
GO


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SourceTable] ON
INSERT [dbo].[SourceTable] ([SourceTableID], [SourceTitle], [SourceContent]) VALUES (1, N'blog1', N'blogdesc1')
INSERT [dbo].[SourceTable] ([SourceTableID], [SourceTitle], [SourceContent]) VALUES (2, N'blog2', N'blogdesc2')
INSERT [dbo].[SourceTable] ([SourceTableID], [SourceTitle], [SourceContent]) VALUES (3, N'blog3', N'blogdesc3')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SourceTable] OFF
```

**Query to insert data in table**

```
CREATE TABLE #SummaryOfChanges(actionType NVARCHAR(50),ThreadID NVARCHAR(40),SourceContent NVARCHAR(40))

MERGE INTO  Threads AS d
USING (SELECT SourceTableID,SourceTitle,SourceContent FROM SourceTable) AS s
ON 1 = 2 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ThreadTitle)
    VALUES (s.SourceTitle)
    OUTPUT $action, Inserted.ThreadID, s.SourceContent INTO #SummaryOfChanges;

MERGE INTO  Posts AS d
USING (SELECT ThreadID,SourceContent FROM #SummaryOfChanges) AS s
ON d.ThreadID = s.ThreadID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET  d.PostContent= s.SourceContent
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ThreadID,PostContent)
    VALUES (ThreadID,s.SourceContent);

DROP TABLE #SummaryOfChanges
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Wow. This is it, thank you! Also, `ON 1 = 2` is a bit hackish, isn't it? ;)

Comment: We mainly used MERGE when we want to Insert and Update the date from one table to another table based on some column. In your case only insert is there so i have put such type of condition.